# SQL Server database log file increasing very fast

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server database with one log file and it is growing very fast.

But it is happening after I shrink the file before that it was good.

My database recovery model is FULL recovery.

Please help with it.

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2012/07/27/how-to-shrink-the-sql-server-log/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant transaction log...

If you use FULL recovery model,

to reclaim a space in the transaction logs or shrink it, the log (or database) should be backed up first. If you use also CDC or Replication, even backup is not enough. The space can be reclaimed only after Log Reader Agent read the transaction logs.

The transaction log is growing fast if there are many DB changes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the log file was appropriately sized for your traffic before you shrank it. To paraphrase Elsa from the movie Frozen "Let it grow!". That is, unless you had an event that you can point to that made the it much larger than it typically is, the log file will likely be appropriately sized given your transactional volume.